# JSON.Net Complex JSON Structure build

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to build a structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "username":"aaa",
  "password":"bbb",
  "inputs" : [ {
    "name" : "Company",
    "value" : "05375"
  }, {
    "name" : "GLDate",
    "value" : "09/15/2018"
  } ],
  "detailInputs" : [ {
    "name" : "GridData",
    "repeatingInputs" : [ {
      "inputs" : [ {
        "name" : "ReceiptNbr",
        "value" : "98USZJ4PR8UA"
      }, {
        "name" : "Payor",
        "value" : "294677"
      } ]
    }, {
      "inputs" : [ {
        "name" : "ReceiptNbr",
        "value" : "2XDT4I5185ZI"
      }, {
        "name" : "Payor",
        "value" : "294677"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I have done the following so far and am missing the last input structure:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public List<Input> inputs { get; set; }
    public List<DetailInput> detailInputs { get; set; }
}

public class Input
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class DetailInput
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<RepeatingInput> repeatingInputs { get; set; }
}

public class RepeatingInput
{
    public List<Input2> inputs { get; set; }
}

public class Input2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

            RootObject preJSONData = new RootObject();
            List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
            List<DetailInput> detailInputs = new List<DetailInput>();
            List<RepeatingInput> repeatingInputs = new List<RepeatingInput>();
            List<Input2> inputs2 = new List<Input2>();

            preJSONData.username = "aaa";
            preJSONData.password = "bbb";

            /*-- PART I */
            Input input = new Input();
            input.name = "Company";
            input.value = "05375";
            inputs.Add(input);

            input = new Input();
            input.name = "GLDate";
            input.value = "09/15/2018";
            inputs.Add(input);


            DetailInput dInput = new DetailInput();
            dInput.name = "GridData";
            dInput.repeatingInputs = repeatingInputs;
            detailInputs.Add(dInput);

            /*-- PART 3 */
            RepeatingInput rInput = new RepeatingInput();
            repeatingInputs.Add(rInput);

            /*-- PART 4 */
            Input2 input2 = new Input2();
            input2.name = "ReceiptNbr";
            input2.value = "98USZJ4PR8UA";
            inputs2.Add(input2);



            preJSONData.inputs = inputs;
            preJSONData.detailInputs = detailInputs;

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(preJSONData);
```

The output that i am getting in json is:
"{\"username\":\"aaa\",\"password\":\"bbb\",\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"Company\",\"value\":\"05375\"},{\"name\":\"GLDate\",\"value\":\"09/15/2018\"}],\"detailInputs\":[{\"name\":\"GridData\",\"repeatingInputs\":[{\"inputs\":null}]}]}".

What am i missing? Please help.

thanks
Ben

Comment: it looks fine and the `\"` is just a way to escape `"`.

Comment: You are close to a [mcve]. What is missing is the expected output. And a little formatting wouldn't hurt.

Comment: A quick observation: `inputs2` is filled but never assigned to anything.

Comment: Also, you can and probaly should merge the `Input` and `Input2` classes.

Comment: How do i assign inputs2? Also if I merge the 2 classes, what should the code look like?  Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Is it that the entire thing is escaped into a JSON string?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that clearly. The inputs within repeatinginputs is empty.

Comment: If you overload the ctors you will have less tedious code to write when using that thing